# vuejs - can't get dayjs working in browser

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to show dates diffForHumans based on this guide: https://www.talvbansal.me/blog/human-readable-dates-with-dayjs-in-vue-js/

So I'm trying to load DayJS as component in my VueJS app this way:

```
<script src="{{ asset('/vendor/vuejs/vue.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/vendor/vue-dayjs/dayjs.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  Vue.component("dayjs", dayjs);

  Vue.filter('formatDateDiffForHumans', function(value){
    if (!value) return null;
    return dayjs(value).fromNow();
  });

  var app = new Vue({
    el:'#vue_app',
    data:{
      ......
    }
  });

</script>

.....

<span>@{{ t.object.created_at | formatDateDiffForHumans }}</span>
```

Then I'm getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: dayjs(...).fromNow is not a function"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `dayjs` is not a Vue component, so it's not sure why you're loading it as such: `Vue.component("dayjs", dayjs);`. The link you have in your post precisely describes how you should import the plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is two fold:

1. `dayjs` is **not** a VueJS component, so it does not make sense to use `Vue.component("dayjs", dayjs);` on it
2. You did not have the required dependencies for `.fromNow()` to work:

   - You will need to [use the `RelativeTime` plugin as mentioned in the documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/from-now#docsNav), and
   - You will need to [extend `dayjs` with the plugin](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/loading-into-browser), i.e. `dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_relativeTime);`

**Pro tip: Make sure you read the documentation of plugins that you're using.** They often contain all the proof-of-concept code and instructions to get things up and running. Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
// Extend DayJS with plugin
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_relativeTime);

Vue.filter('formatDateDiffForHumans', function(value) {
  if (!value) return null;
  return dayjs(value).fromNow();
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue_app',
  data: {
    myDate: new Date(2018, 8, 18)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.3/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.10.3/plugin/relativeTime.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue_app">
  <span>@{{ myDate | formatDateDiffForHumans }}</span>
</div>
```